# How does pause() work?

Tags: c

I'm completely noob in c. I have to write a function `mypause()` that should have a functionality similar to the `pause()` system call, and test the `mypause()` function in a program that repeatedly blocks waiting for a signal.
How does te `pause()` function works?? Can't I just do a `mypause()` like this:

```
fprintf( stderr, "press any key to continue\n" );
```

in order for the program to block and wait for an signal?

Have in mind that I can't ever use `pause()` or `sigpause()`.

Comment: So you want to wait for a key stroke?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Should be tagged as such? Anyway, I think you haven't quite understand the problem you want to solve. The pause() call does NOT wait for user input.

Comment: I.e. keyboard events are not signals in the sense here required.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm I've been told the homework tag has been retired

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause  Pause waits for a signal (a sort of kernel communication), not keyboard input.  Anyway, fprintf won't pause the program at all.

Comment: Your task is probably to use another blocking system call then, like `select` perhaps, which will break out when interrupted, and you can set a flag in a signal handler to check. Your mypause will then return when the flag is set. Implementing something that waits for a signal has to involve a blocking syscall and a signal handler somewhere along the way. (Bear in mind that in the context of the `pause` function, "signal" refers to something very specific. Read your course notes or Stevens APUE or "man 7 signal".)

Comment: I think the program should be blocked until the mypause() fuction gives him permission to contiue. Yeah something like waiting for a key stroke.

Comment: @Luis: Well, we can't guess for you. Please just tell us clearly what it is you're trying to do. Note that the only two common ways to wait for a specific signal in a race-free way are to use sigsuspend specifically, or use a self-pipe with select. If you attempt to roll your own solution, it'll probably be incorrect, so maybe thinking this through is what your teacher wants you to learn? Keep reading and thinking until you can come up with a precise question.

Comment: You're right Nicholas Wilson, I'll do that. Do you have some book/website you could recommend?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`pause()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Pause.html) function blocks until a signal arrives. User inputs are not signals. A signal can be emitted by another process or the system itself.

Pressing `Ctrl-C` for instance, causes your shell to send a `SIGINT` signal to the current running process, which in *normal* cases causes the process to be killed.

In order to emulate the behaviour of `pause` in ISO C99 you could write something like the following. The code is commented, if you have a question about this implementation, please ask.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

/**
 * The type sig_atomic_t is used in C99 to guarantee
 * that a variable can be accessed/modified in an atomic way
 * in the case an interruption (reception of a signal for example) happens.
 */
static volatile sig_atomic_t done_waiting = 0;

static void     handler()
{
  printf("Signal caught\n");
  done_waiting = 1;
}

void    my_pause()
{
  /**
   *  In ISO C, the signal system call is used
   *  to call a specific handler when a specified
   *  signal is received by the current process.
   *  In POSIX.1, it is encouraged to use the sigaction APIs.
   **/
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
  done_waiting = 0;
  while ( !done_waiting )
    ;
}

int     main()
{
  my_pause();
  printf("Hey ! The first call to my_pause returned !\n");
  my_pause();
  printf("The second call to my_pause returned !\n");
  return (0);
}
```

Note this example only works with the `SIGINT` signal. To handle an additional set of signals, you can use other calls to `signal()` with different signal numbers or use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with a mask referencing all the desired signals.

A complete list of the signals availables on your system can be found in you `<signal.h>` include.

Comment: Busy-waiting is bad. Put a sleep in that loop.

Comment: (sleep will wake up early for signals)

Comment: Thanks Halim Qarroum this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Dave You can't just use sleep, because of the classic race condition: when sleep returns, you'd have to use an if statement to check whether we should sleep again. If the signal arrives in that moment, you're "stuffed". That's exactly why sigsuspend was invented. See my comment above: A more clever signal handler with a self-pipe is the only other way (sane) to implement pause with a loop in a race-free way.

Comment: @Halim Stick to your guns; your answer is good. Busy wait may be ugly, but is technically correct and is perhaps the best you can do in ISO C without touching POSIX. Trying to do something fancy in a loop is a classic place programmers make mistakes.