# Is there any standard Linux C++ input libraries out and used?

Tags: c++, linux, input

Aspiring gamedev using Linux C++ g++-4.7

I've done my research on time steps, game loops and do not user getch, focus on loop more than input cause its important etc...

They say little about the workings of Input(), Movement(), ProcessInput() which are the same egg in which I actually need.

I have no plans in shelling out or anything that might deal damage. I do program my own game loop.

They convinced me it's simple but what libraries do I use to get proper inputs for my game loop if it would come from keyboard and mouse?

Please do not post windows answers.

I already read this:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop

[C++ wait for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257544/c-wait-for-user-input)

[Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: Please do not put out of scope cause game-dev SE pointed me to stackoverflow

Comment: Well, it *is* off topic. I guess people over at gamedev.se were misinformed. OT : I recommend [SDL2](http://libsdl.org/).

Comment: Honesty they wanna deal more on unity and controlled engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your requirements are, but the SFML libraries are cross-platform and allow you to view the state of the input devices without blocking.

Home page: http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php

Tutorials page: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/

Input tutorial: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/window-inputs.php