# How to ask for input after text to show the next line in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a total newbie to C++ and I need to have 3 line of text and after every line I have to ask the user to press enter to continue. How can I do it?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Es esmu dators.";
    std::cout << "Es zinu C++.";
    std::cout << "C++ ir programmesanas valoda";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getchar()` after each line. To use `getchar()` you must include `cstdio`.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Es esmu dators.\n";
    getchar();
    std::cout << "Es zinu C++.\n";
    getchar();
    std::cout << "C++ ir programmesanas valoda\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21257728/1601729) answer:

---

Several ways to do so, here are some possible one-line approaches:

Use getch() (need #include ).

Use getchar() (expected for Enter, need #include ).

Use cin.get() (expected for Enter, need #include ).

Use system("pause") (need #include ).

PS: This method will also print Press any key to continue . . . on the screen. (seems perfect choice for you :))

---

You should also perform a quick search on the site to see if your question has been asked before, going forward.

Comment: Note that `system("pause")` is Windows-specific. Just tested in Unix environment and when run, exits with print-out: "sh: pause: command not found"

Comment: Fair enough I'll edit the answer.