# Disappearing Console window when coding c++ in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im having a technical issue while trying to code C++ in visual Studio. My code was working fine until it required me to use input from the user, so i coded a simple program like the one below

```
int chairs(void) {

 int count;

 cout << “Enter the number of chairs: “;

 cin >> count;

 return count;

}
```

When i run the code the console window opens and allows the user to enter the number of chairs, however, once the value has been entered the window immediatly closes and theres no output in visual studios own console window. How can i fix this issue? is there a certain plug-in or settings i need to change? I knoww you can code your own settings in user settings. 
Thankyou

Comment: To stop it you can use getch() before the return statement.

Comment: You can use one of the methods mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21257728/4980722)

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?  That is, your entire program. It's entirely possibly your program is crashing after `chairs` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add getch(); before the return statement. It will then wait for you to press any button to close.

Comment: it says getch(); is undefined

Comment: add #include<conio. h>

Comment: okay thankyou. Do you also know how to fix the issue where the program doesnt close? it just keeps running

Comment: there might be an infinite loop in the program. need to see the program to identify!

Comment: `getch()` is the C way to read a char. The C++ way is `std::cin.get()` instead

Answer (score 1):

From the main menu, select Tools,then Options.

Make sure this setting **is not** enabled under Debugging: "Automatically close console window when debugging stops".

[image]

Comment: theres no option for this